# Can a base destructor really be overridden by a derived destructor in C++?

Tags: c++11, overriding, virtual-destructor

All over the web, as well as in Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ book, I see statements like, "If a base destructor is declared virtual then it is overridden by a derived class's destructor."

But, why is it called overriding? Isn't it slightly different than the "usual" way of overriding functions? By usual, I mean a typical virtual function in a derived class, sharing the same method signature as that in the base. In that usual case, either the base version or the derived version is ignored depending on the actual object pointed to by a pointer.... Let's not get into details of how overriding works in the usual sense.

But in cases of destructors, the base destructor **WILL eventually** be called, no matter what. Also, its name is different. Why is it then called overriding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it then called overriding?

Because it overrides the destructor of the base class.

Consider this:

```
struct Foo
{
   ~Foo() {}
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   ~Bar() {} // This does not override ~Foo.
};

Foo* fptr = new Bar;
delete fptr;  // ~Foo() is called.
```

`~Bar()` will be called if the pointer is `Bar*`.

```
Bar* bptr = new Bar;
delete bptr;  // ~Bar() is called.
```

However, if you change `Foo` to:

```
struct Foo
{
   virtrual ~Foo() {}
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   ~Bar() {} // This overrides ~Foo.
};
```

then use

```
Foo* fptr = new Bar;
delete fptr;  // ~Bar() is called.
              // ~Bar() overrides ~Foo().
```

Comment: In the last situation, my opinion differs with yours. ~Bar() is called and then ~Foo() is called. That was my original point! Why is it then called overriding?

Comment: @softwarelover, You are right - `~Bar()` is called first but then `~Foo()` is called before `~Bar()` returns. `~Bar()` is still called an overriding destructor because without the overriding nature, `delete fptr` will not end up calling `~Bar()`.

Comment: I see. The fact that ~Foo() is called, sort of, within ~Bar(), makes this overridding different from the usual cases of overriding where functions are typical virtual functions rather than destructors. Doesn't it?

Comment: @softwarelover, yes it does. Constructors and destructors are special functions and have their own idiosyncrasies.